# SVN: how to skip empty commit message warning?

Tags: svn, commit

I am using SVN to sync my notes, so i dont need commit messsages. when i do a commit without a message i get this warning:

```
$ svn ci

Log message unchanged or not specified
(a)bort, (c)ontinue, (e)dit:
```

how can i configure svn to skip this warning message?

Comment: This can give you an idea: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/VIM-vs-subversion-strange-behavior-td1182554.html, i'm not sure, but possible you can skip/disable it, creating a pre-commit hook that in case of empty message will setup a default one, tricky way to resolve your issue!

Comment: commit with `-m .`?